# Iframe, load content in self

Tags: html, iframe

When i load (any) an iframe, example.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

And click the HTML tutorial link, i get redirected from file:///G:/text.html (my local system) to http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

How can i instead load the content inside the iframe on my local system, that the anchor points to?
..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Does this only happen with w3schools? It might be a script on the w3schools site to prevent iframing their site

Comment: Links on W3Schools may be targetted to `top` or they may be running JavaScript to "break out" of iframes.